# Boot order not saved Lenovo u410

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

So I am trying to boot a bootable flash drive with Windows 10 on it on Lenovo U410.  I entered the BIOS and changed to legacy with legacy priority but when changed the values of the boot order they just won't save.  Windows boot manager always stays up and no matter what I do.  For example, there is a small button on the side of the power button that offers the boot menu option.  But still, when selected, it automatically boots Windows without asking.

Since Windows 8 just hibernates itself and stores all the info on the disc, I cannot press F12 or whatever button to access the boot menu.  I tried to reboot Windows indicating the device I want to boot using that strange advanced menu that Windows 8 has, but with no success; it still directly boots the Windows. How can I access the boot menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To boot to Win10 from a flash drive, you need to have UEFI boot enabled for the USB device in the BIOS.  Legacy won't work.  What's happening is that it's ignoring the boot options because it's detecting only the hard drive as valid UEFI boot device.

Lenovo suggests disabling "safe boot" in the BIOS and pushing F12 to manually bring up the boot menu as the computer is starting: [UEFI Bootable Readme](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/uefi_bootable_usb_user_guide_281.pdf)

Comment: nope ... not working.Put it to uefi disabled the secure boot still goes straight to Windows boot settings not saving, F12 no working and I even remade the flash drive

Comment: In order to narrow down the possible causes, could you please make a bootable usb image of `YUMI` ( http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and try to boot off of it?  The results will tell us whether the problem is specifically UEFI related or not.